# PhanomJS Evaluate

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, phantomjs

> console.log(_killer) gives undefined.

```
_killer = _pageInstance.evaluate(function() {
    var  storres = [];
    jQuery('.comment-container#pull-request-activity').children().each(
        function(index, value) {
            if (
                jQuery(value)[0].className !== 'activity-item diff-comment-activity'
            ) {
                jQuery(value)[0].remove();
            } else {
            storres.push(value);
            jQuery(value)[0].remove();
        }
    });

    return storres;
});



DOM 
   <li class="activity-item diff-comment-activity" data-activityid="178071"><div></div></li>
<li class="activity-item diff-comment-activity" data-activityid="178070"><div></div></li>
<li class="activity-item diff-comment-activity" data-activityid="178069"><div></div></li>
```

above is a repeated element and i want to pull out this from DOM.

> I am using version 0.2.5 of node-phantom

Similar kind of question are available on forum but none is helping. I am using `node bridge` for `phantomjs`.

Any help ?

Comment: What exact node-phantom bridge do you use? (please, provide a link) Also, is there a way for us to have a look at the target page? If not, please provide a relevant sample of DOM to examine.

Comment: DOM i can't provide but if i run this part in my console.. It works as expected that is..  It pulls out the matched elements and store in storres.

Comment: My goalnis just pull out the matched elements,  storing it in a array and returning the array to "outer world"

Comment: If you look at the documentation of the bridge you're using (there are multiple), you should see that the `evaluate` function takes at least two arguments: 1. a function to be evaluated in the page context and 2. a callback function when the result is available. Usually, nothing is returned.

Comment: Yup.. Tried that one also.. By adding a function as a second argument and then assign the resukt from first argument's result to a global variable..  But no luck

Comment: Yes you can provide a portion of DOM by copying a part of it from devtools as code into the question. Didn't answer about node bridge btw.

Comment: Sure will do it..

Comment: I have added the DOM in the question itself.